# Select2 (no results match) with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I have a select2 (ui-selecet) and need that when there is no result or all the options have been selected (multi-select) will appear a message and the option to open a modal.

When I click on the button it does not open the modal and does not execute the function.

Select2 Component:

```
formatNoMatches: function () {
return "Nenhum resultado encontrado. <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' ng-click='modalOpen()'>" + "Cadastrar" + "</button>";
}
```

Select2 View:

```
<select ui-select2="select2Options" multiple="multiple" ng-model="select" style="width: 100%" data-placeholder="Selecione uma pessoa">`
<option value=""></option>
<option ng-repeat="person in people" value="{{person}}">{{person.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Obs.: I think it should be a matter of scope, but I do not know how to solve it.

Would anyone have any ideas or solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I managed to solve it like this:

- In the component **Select2.js** I made the change so it displays a button and call an **OpenModal(this)** function.
- I put a **_myOptions** variable that gets the same arguments as the variable **args** line 3440.
- Next I use this variable (_myOptions) and get the data-target.
- In the controller I created a **$scope.select2Options** where I pass the modal target that is accessed in **Select2.js**

With this when the results finish or do not have it a message appears and when clicking the button it opens the modal.

**ViewHTML:**

```
<select ui-select2="select2Options" data-target="#animal" id="select2Callback" multiple="multiple" ng-model="person" >
                            <option value=""></option>
                            <option ng-repeat="person in people" value="{{person}}">{{person.name}}</option>
                        </select>
```

**Select2.js Component:**

```
formatNoMatches: function () {
        var target = _myOptions[0].target;
        return "Nenhum resultado encontrado. <button type='button' class='btn btn-default' data-toggle='modal' "+
               "data-target='"+target+"' onClick='openModal(this)'> Cadastrar </button>";
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.select2Options = {
            allowClear: true,
            multiple: true,
            target: '#teste'
        };
```

**ModalDirective:**

```
angular.module('modalDirectives', [])
    .directive('modal', function () {
        var ddo = {};
        ddo.restrict = "E";
        ddo.transclude = true;
        ddo.scope = {
            modalid: '@',
            title: '@'
        };
        ddo.templateUrl = "/app/js/directives/modal.html";
        return ddo;
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to use `$compile` to dynamically generate and compile the button so that the `ng-click` is effectively attached/registered. The example uses a container element to hold the button so that it can be easily append after compilation, it is not necessary, you can append it to `<body>` or any other DOM element.

You'll need to inject `$document` and `$compile` for this to work.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- some container to append generated button to -->
<div id="foo"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
formatNoMatches: function () {
    // some container element to hold the dynamically generated button
    var $container = angular.element($document[0].getElementById('foo'));

    // button markup as angular element wrapped in jqLite
    var button = angular.element('<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="modalOpen()">Cadastrar</button>');

    // compile using angular's $compile service
    button = $compile(button)($scope);

    // append the button into the container
    $container.empty().append(button);
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: It did not work, they look like they are in two different scopes (RootScope and Scope), I'll try to manipulate it by DOM and inject the command to open Modal;

But thank you very much for the help.